# Remote login to decoupled website with python and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website www.seek.com.au. I am trying to test the possibility to remote login using Python request module. The site is Front end is designed using React and hence I don't see any form action component in www.seek.com.au/sign-in

When I run the below code, I see the response code as `200` indicating success, but I doubt if it's actually successful. The main concern is which URL to use in case if there is no action element in the login submit form.

```py
import requests

payload = {'email': <username>, 'password': <password>}
url = 'https://www.seek.com.au'

with requests.Session() as s:
    response_op = s.post(url, data=payload)
    # print the response status code
    print(response_op.status_code)
    print(response_op.text)
```

When i examine the output data (response_op.text), i see word 'Sign in' and 'Register' in output which indicate the login failed. If its successful, the users first name will be shown in the place. What am I doing wrong here ?

*P.S: I am not trying to scrape data from this website but I am trying to login to a similar website.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import requests

payload={"email": "test@test.com", "password": "passwordtest", "rememberMe": True}
url = "https://www.seek.com.au:443/userapi/login"

with requests.Session() as s:
    response_op = s.post(url, json=payload)
    # print the response status code
    print(response_op.status_code)
    print(response_op.text)
```

You are sending the request to the wrong url.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Fozoro. That did work. But may i know how you found the target URL. That was the key to the entire thing.

Comment: @Vidhu There are many tools out there that you can use. I personally all ways use [Burp Suite Comunity edition](https://portswigger.net/burp) it lets you intercept packets sent from your computer/browser to the server.